# Issue regarding json array

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON array and I am adding items.  I want to display this JSON in a particular format.

My code:

```
var array = new List<object>();
array.Add(new
        {
        Dealname = dealname,
        Ticketcount = tictnum,
        OriginalPrice = origpri,
        Dealsticketcount = dealsticktnu,
        dealprice = dp,
        totalprice = totamnt,
        });

   array.Add(new
       {
      ItemName = itnme,
      Price = price,
      Quantity = quant,
      });
```

This is what my array looks like.  I am adding some items.  Right now it produces the following output:

```
[{"Dealname":"unnideal","Ticketcount":"25","OriginalPrice":"100","Dealsticketcount":"1","dealprice":"200","totalprice":"300},{"ItemName":"popcorn","Price":"100","Quantity":"1"},{"ItemName":"piza","Price":"100","Quantity":"1"}]
```

But i need my output like this:

```
[{"Dealname":"unnideal","Ticketcount":"25","OriginalPrice":"100","Dealsticketcount":"1","dealprice":"200","totalprice":"300"},"Offers"[{"ItemName":"popcorn","Price":"100","Quantity":"1"},{"ItemName":"piza","Price":"100","Quantity":"1"}]]
```

That is, I need an array for offers.  How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that your parent object, and child "offer" objects are not related, when Offers needs to be part of the main object.

Try something like this:

```
var array = new List<object>();
var offers = new List<object>();
offers.Add(new
       {
      ItemName = itnme,
      Price = price,
      Quantity = quant,
      });

array.Add(new
        {
        Dealname = dealname,
        Ticketcount = tictnum,
        OriginalPrice = origpri,
        Dealsticketcount = dealsticktnu,
        dealprice = dp,
        totalprice = totamnt,
        Offers = offers
        });
```

Comment: :Thank you for the answer,its working fine,but it creates duplication in the case of offers.Some deals dont have offers.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan.S well deals without offers would just have an empty/null array for `Offers` then.

Comment: This is the output iam getting . In megadeal there are no offers ,but the same offer  repeated .[{"Dealname":"unnideal","Ticketcount":"25","OriginalPrice":"100","Dealsticketcount":"1","dealprice":"200"
,"totalprice":"300","offers":[{"ItemName":"popcorn","Price":"100","Quantity":"1"},{"ItemName":"piza"
,"Price":"100","Quantity":"1"}]},{"Dealname":"megadeal","Ticketcount":"20","OriginalPrice":"100","Dealsticketcount"
:"1","dealprice":"200","totalprice":"100","offers":[{"ItemName":"popcorn","Price":"100","Quantity":"1"
},{"ItemName":"piza","Price":"100","Quantity":"1"}]}]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want another property named "Offers"?

```
var array = new List<object>();

var offers = new[]
{
    new {ItemName = itnme, Price = price, Quantity = quant}
    ...
};

array.Add(new
    {
        Dealname = dealname,
        Ticketcount = tictnum,
        OriginalPrice = origpri,
        Dealsticketcount = dealsticktnu,
        dealprice = dp,
        totalprice = totamnt,
        Offers = offers  // adding Offers as a property here
    });
```

This should produce a JSON like the following:

```
[
  {
    "Dealname": "unnideal",
    "Ticketcount": "25",
    "OriginalPrice": "100",
    "Dealsticketcount": "1",
    "dealprice": "200",
    "totalprice": "300",
    "Offers": [
      {
        "ItemName": "popcorn",
        "Price": "100",
        "Quantity": "1"
      },
      {
        "ItemName": "piza",
        "Price": "100",
        "Quantity": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```